# Error while translating text using GoogleTranslateApi

Tags: c#

I am getting "An exception of type 'Google.API.GoogleServiceException' occurred in GoogleTranslateAPI.dll but was not handled in user code" exception when trying to translate a text(ex: Home) using GoogleTranslateApi. Below is my code:

using Google.API.Translate;

```
class GoogleTranslateService : ITranslationService
{
    private readonly TranslateClient client = new TranslateClient("http://www.google.com");

    string FromLanguage { get; set; }
    string ToLanguage { get; set; }

    public GoogleTranslateService(string from, string to)
    {
        FromLanguage = from;
        ToLanguage = to;
    }

    public string Translate(string text)
    {
        return client.Translate(text, FromLanguage, ToLanguage);
    }
}
```

Attached is the screen shot of the exception:

[Exception Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eqhk.png)

[Exception Details Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uilk5.png)

Do anyone have any idea for resolving this exception?

Comment: What is the Exception detail?

Comment: @DarrenYoung I have updated the question with a new screen shot for "Exception Details". Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: It tells you the error in the Details.  You are using the deprecated API.  You need to switch to the new one, which is a paid service for the most part.

Comment: @DarrenYoung I am doing a POC for language translation. Are there any open source translator API's that I can use?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I know that `Bing` used to be free up to a certain number of queries/characters.  I don't know if that is still the same.